# Blogs posts on an alternative page?

Tags: wordpress

After reading many posts and reading tutorials on the WWW, I still can't seem to get my posts to go to my alternative blog page.

> I currently have a front static page called "Home"  and a blog page
>   called "Blog"
>
> I set the Reading settings as follows:

```
  Front Page Displays - A Static Page 
  Front page: Home 
  Posts Page: Blog
```

Now when I create posts, I do not getting any of them to show up on my blog page. Instead the page displays a menu with the following items:

```
Pages
Archives
Categories
Meta
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a blog page template, you need to have a page template for it. You can create page templates by following [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) link.

Comment: blog template? I do not have a blog template option.

Comment: @JakeSays: On the top right, see screen options and click on it. It will have the option to show page template.

Comment: I did that already, there is no template called blog template

Comment: The theme must not have a template for blog. Are you creating your own theme? Also, it is not necessary it would be called blog template. Check for any page template in that area and with trial and error you will know which one is for the blog.

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom theme. We didn't have a blog on our page when the site was developed, but would like to add one now

Comment: I see, is there not a plugin that would allow me to create a blog easier ?  :)

Comment: You need a page template. There is no other way to have a blog.